# Run Powershell script in the background through Intune

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that connects to Azure AD to fetch data and create an Outlook signature.

It is currently deployed via GPO, but since the IT Manager wants to move to Azure AD and Intune, I have to find a way to deploy it via InTune (either msi or exe).

I am currently wrapping it in an exe using the following script that uses iexpress: [Technet: Create-EXEFromps1](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Create-EXEFromps1-Create-efc8436c)

However if I run the exe it's not running in the background. Anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: You could package it into an MSI and use the `Run` keys in registry to execute it at logon. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.lieben.nu/liebensraum/2016/09/ems-case-running-a-powershell-logonscript-like-onedrivemapper-on-azuread-joined-machines-through-intune/) that covers that option.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that tomorrow morning at work :)

Comment: This worked fine! thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As James C. said:
package it into an MSI and use the Run keys in registry to execute it at logon. Here's a tutorial that covers that option.